# Desarrollar entorno gráfico para python con lenguaje web

Tags: python

Se que esto no va a ser una pregunta de código pero llevo un tiempo buscando información y no lo conseguir entender.

La cosa es que yo trabajo con Python y diferentes librerías, desde NumPy, Pandas, MatPlotLib, hasta bibliotecas de visión cómo OpenCV.

La cosa es que quiero hacerle interfaz gráfica a algunos de mis programas, entonces de entrada he visto que lo que normalmente se usa es TKinter o PyQT (hay alguno más pero eso son los que predominaban) **pero** personalmente no me gusta la estética que tienen, además yo también tengo conocimientos en html, css, js y en menor medida php y sql. Entonces mi idea sería saber si es posible hacer la intefaz gráfica de mis programas Python con estos últimos (y así aprovechar mis conocimientos ahora sin uso) y que por lo tanto se ejecutasen desde el navegador de manera offline, es decir, emplear html, css y js simplemente para hacer la estética ya que estos me parecen muchísimo más potentes. A continuación dejo un ejemplo muy muy básico.

```css
body{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#contenedor {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Detector de caras mediante OpenCV</h1>
<p> Pulsa el botón ejecutar para arrancar el programa hecho en OpenCV, encienda tu cámara y detecte si hay caras en la imagen.</p>
<div id=contenedor>
  <input type="button" value="Ejecutar">
</div>
```

Me gustaría por ejemplo esto que he mostrado, o poner un botón y que muestre gráficos, etc , etc. Las opciones son infinitas.

He visto que existe Flask y Django pero no tengo claro si realmente es para esto o no. Entonces mi pregunta es, saber si lo que quiero hacer es posible, si tiene contras, y si Django o Flask son lo que debo aprender u otro lenguaje?

Es que me puse a leer y ver tutoriales de Django y cuando leo a grandes rasgos su utilidad me parece que sí, pero cuando me explican cosas no termino de ver claro si realmente es esto, entonces, no tengo problema en ponerme a aprender algo nuevo, pero necesito enfocar todo mi esfuerzo a aquello que realmente sea mi objetivo.

Se que no es una pregunta que cumple todos los requisitos, pero no pretenedo abrir debate, simplemente saber la respuesta a que lenguaje/framework debo enfocarme.

¡Saludy gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si quieres usar HTML/CSS/JS como frontend y python para el backend tienes básicamente dos opciones:

1. Usar un navegador web estándar para mostrar el frontend, y un servidor escrito en python para el backend, que atienda las peticiones que el navegador le haga y le proporcione las respuestas apropiadas.
2. Usar un *toolkit* para Python con capacidades gráficas, como Tk, Qt, etc. que proporcione un elemento de tipo "canvas html" por así decir, en el que mostrar la interfaz de usuario.

En cualquiera de los dos casos tienes que resolver la comunicación entre la interfaz html y la funcionalidad python que ejecuta el código. En el primer caso la comunicación será HTTP y los datos intercambiados probablemente json (además de tipos específicos para imágenes por ejemplo). En el segundo caso dependerá de qué plataforma elijas y francamente no sé cómo van.

En el caso 1, para el backend podrías usar Django o Flask. Lo bueno de esta solución es que lo mismo te da que el servidor esté ejecutándose localmente (es decir, en la misma máquina que el navegador Web) o remotamente (en un servidor en la nube). Lo malo de esta solución es que es muy complejo. Tienes que aprender sobre desarrollo web, que no es trivial.

El caso 2 apenas lo conozco, pero sé que es posible.

En cualquiera de los dos casos, yo iría a soluciones "precocinadas", algunas de las cuales pueden ser:

- [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) Notebooks. Estos encajarían en la modalidad 1, si bien son un caso un poco particular. El servidor (que puede ser tu propia máquina) ejecuta un *kernel* python. El cliente, que es el navegador web, presenta al usuario unas celdas donde puede teclear código python, que es enviado al servidor para su ejecución, y después el cliente muestra la respuesta, que puede ser texto, tablas, gráficos, etc. No está orientado a hacer GUIs, sino a la investigación usando Python para el análisis de datos, pero es altamente configurable, pues puedes crear "celdas" que contengan Markdown o html y hacerlas interactuar con el *backend*. Dependiendo de lo que tengas en mente podría ser suficiente.
- [Anvil](https://anvil.works/) es un proveedor que te da una aplicación web en la que, arrastrando y soltando componentes, creas tu interfaz gráfica que se ejecutará en el navegador y será atendida por un servidor Python. Es una solución "propietaria", pues los servidores python corren en sus máquinas, pero de nuevo según lo que quieras hacer puede ser una buena opción.
- [htmlpy](https://htmlpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/) usa el enfoque 2, basándose en el componente HTML de Qt. Es lo más parecido quizás a lo que planteas en tu pregunta. La interfaz la creas en HTML/CSS/JS y es mostrada en una ventana manejada por Qt, y puedes asociar eventos en botones a código python. Tengo que decir que no lo he probado, pero me ha parecido interesante.
- [cefpython](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) Este utiliza Chromium como componente para renderizar el HTML. Por tanto en filosofía es similar a Electron (el framework usado para crear, por ejemplo, el editor Visual Studio Code), sólo que Electron se programa enteramente en  javascript, mientras que cefpython sería en python. Tampoco lo he probado y un vistazo a su documentación me ha dado la impresión de ser bastante complejo.

En resumen, ambos enfoques me parecen bastante complicados, aunque no he probado todos. La ventaja del enfoque 1 es que lo que aprendas te será útil también para crear aplicaciones cliente/servidor.

Según tus necesidades, pudiera ser que Jupyter fuera suficiente.

### Actualización

Se me olvidaba [brython](http://brython.info/index.html) pero probablemente no sea esto lo que necesitas, pues es una implementación en JavaScript de python (o de un un subconjunto de python), que te permite incrustar código Python en una web, que se ejecutaría en el lado cliente. Esto por supuesto no te permitirá usar bibliotecas como numpy, opencv, etc, pero sí al menos cambiar el lenguaje de scripting del navegador y podría ser útil en otros escenarios.